# How to check from starting position of string contains a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, contains, indexof

I want to check a string contains another string or not. If contains it should display in specified grid.

in my list i have titles like ["abcd","fabcdgh","fgh","sdfgabcd","hgtabc","abcdefg"] and i want to check "abcd".
Here Is my code

```
        <div class="picture-item__details">
        <figcaption class="picture-item__title"><?php echo $title ?></figcaption>
        </div>

  const searchText = evt.target.value.toLowerCase();
  this.shuffle.filter((element, shuffle) => {

  const titleElement = element.querySelector('.picture-item__title');
  const titleText = titleElement.textContent.toLowerCase().trim();

   return (titleText).indexOf(searchText) !== -1;

    });
```

In html div i am getting title dynamically .at the top i have a search bar ,i am getting Search text from there .
Now i want to check if search bar contains "abcd" it should return ["abcd","abcdefg"] only ,not to search in middle of string.
Which function do I use to find out if title  contains "abcd" check from starting position?

any help appreciated...Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can just change the return statement of your code to

```
return (titleText).indexOf(searchText) === 0;
```

Alternatively, Javascript now conveniently has a [startsWith](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_startswith.asp) method - 
so you can change your return statement to this too

```
return titleText.startsWith(searchText)
```

Comment: After adding  return titleText.startsWith(searchText) ,it does not return any results.and even not getting any console errors to check

Comment: I see, there's a possibility that might be you're on an <ES6 environment. In that case, I'll encourage you to go with the first solution using `indexOf` !

Comment: by using indexOf how can we achieve the expected result.actually i am  newbie to javascript .so i am unable to get expected result .i am using shuffle library.

Comment: For indexOf, it returns the index (position) of where the second string is inside the first.

So when it's 0, it means the second string, `searchText`, is found in position 0 of your first string, `titleText`. Positon 0 means it's right at the start. If it's 1, it means it's at the second position. Aka `bc` found in `abcd`.

Checking for it to be `!== -1`, is equivalent to checking that the second string appears somewhere in the first string

Comment: actually i did not get what you are suggesting . previously i tried with return (titleText[0]).indexOf(searchText) !== -1;by this  in search field if i give a it returns ["abcd","abcdefg"] but after giving "ab" in search field it returns nothing